# How to fix black screen in iPad simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode

my app work just fine on iPhone simulator but when I run it on iPad it show my this black screen

[image: check this image:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try run in terminal:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```